# How to cover exception in code coverage report Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, api, testing, laravel-8

How can I `catch` any exceptions to cover the 100% code coverage report? This only covers the `try` condition in the code.

**Controller**

```
public function getItem()
{
    try {
        // Some code
        return $result;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Log::error($e->getMessage());
        throw new Exception ("$e->getMessage ()", 500);
    }
}
```

**Test file**

```
public function testGetItem() 
{
    $this->get('api/getitem')->assertStatus(200);
}
```

Comment: I understand this is example code and probably not what you're actually doing but doing a try just to catch and log an exception and throw a similar exception is just bad practice. If you want to test the catch block your test case needs to do something that triggers an exception in your code.

Comment: You will need to modify your request so that there is the possibility of an error. I guess there is no real answer without the real code

Answer (score 2):

Testing exceptions is easy in PHPUnit, but doesn't work like you'd expect in Laravel thanks to how it handles exceptions.

To test exceptions in Laravel you first need to disable Laravel exception handling - which if you extend the provided `TestCase`, you can do with the `withoutExceptionHandling()` method.

From there you can use PHPUnit's `expectException()` methods. Here's a small example.

```php
use Tests\TestCase;

class ExceptionTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testExceptionIsThrownOnFailedRequest()
    {
        // Disable exception handling for the test.
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

        // Expect a specific exception class.
        $this->expectException(\Exception::class);

        // Expect a specific exception message.
        $this->expectExceptionMessage('Simulate a throw.');

        // Expect a specific exception code.
        $this->expectExceptionCode(0);

        // Code that triggers the exception.
        $this->get('/stackoverflow');
    }
}
```

Now when the test is run, it'll disable Laravel's exception handling for this test run, then we set some expectations about what should happen, lastly, we call the code that'll fulfill those expectations, in this case, that's a `get()` call to route.

[image: Successfull test case ran]

Now how the expectations are fulfilled will be up to your application.